# Swagger UI is only showing get endpoints.

Tags: java, web-services, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I have several rest end points which I want to expose through swagger. I have downloaded a example of swagger rest 2. When i am viewing the generated json in the swagger ui it is only showing the get endpoints. Post and put endpoints are not shown. Please help.

### this is my web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>
        io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,
        io.swagger.sample.resource
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>api.version</param-name>
      <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
      <param-value>http://localhost:8080/SwaggerWithRest2/api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>swagger.filter</param-name>
      <param-value>io.swagger.sample.util.ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>io.swagger.sample.util.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Bootstrap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.sample.Bootstrap</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### this is my end point class

```
/**
 *  Copyright 2016 SmartBear Software
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

package io.swagger.sample.resource;

import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import io.swagger.sample.data.UserData;
import io.swagger.sample.model.User;
import io.swagger.sample.exception.ApiException;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/user")
@Api(value="/user", description = "Operations about user")
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public class UserResource {
  static UserData userData = new UserData();

  @POST
  @ApiOperation(value = "Create user",
    notes = "This can only be done by the logged in user.",
    position = 1)
  public Response createUser(
      @ApiParam(value = "Created user object", required = true) User user) {
    userData.addUser(user);
    return Response.ok().entity("").build();
  }

  @POST
  @Path("/createWithArray")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Creates list of users with given input array",
    position = 2)
  public Response createUsersWithArrayInput(@ApiParam(value = "List of user object", required = true) User[] users) {
      for (User user : users) {
          userData.addUser(user);
      }
      return Response.ok().entity("").build();
  }

  @POST
  @Path("/createWithList")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Creates list of users with given input array",
    position = 3)
  public Response createUsersWithListInput(@ApiParam(value = "List of user object", required = true) java.util.List<User> users) {
      for (User user : users) {
          userData.addUser(user);
      }
      return Response.ok().entity("").build();
  }

  @PUT
  @Path("/{username}")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Updated user",
    notes = "This can only be done by the logged in user.",
    position = 4)
  @ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid user supplied"),
      @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User not found") })
  public Response updateUser(
      @ApiParam(value = "name that need to be deleted", required = true) @PathParam("username") String username,
      @ApiParam(value = "Updated user object", required = true) User user) {
    userData.addUser(user);
    return Response.ok().entity("").build();
  }

  @DELETE
  @Path("/{username}")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Delete user",
    notes = "This can only be done by the logged in user.",
    position = 5)
  @ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid username supplied"),
      @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User not found") })
  public Response deleteUser(
      @ApiParam(value = "The name that needs to be deleted", required = true) @PathParam("username") String username) {
    if (userData.removeUser(username)) {
      return Response.ok().entity("").build();
    } else {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{username}")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Get user by user name",
    response = User.class,
    position = 0)
  @ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid username supplied"),
      @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User not found") })
  public Response getUserByName(
      @ApiParam(value = "The name that needs to be fetched. Use user1 for testing. ", required = true) @PathParam("username") String username)
    throws ApiException {
    User user = userData.findUserByName(username);
    if (null != user) {
      return Response.ok().entity(user).build();
    } else {
      throw new io.swagger.sample.exception.NotFoundException(404, "User not found");
    }
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/login")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Logs user into the system",
    response = String.class,
    position = 6)
  @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid username/password supplied") })
  public Response loginUser(
      @ApiParam(value = "The user name for login", required = true) @QueryParam("username") String username,
      @ApiParam(value = "The password for login in clear text", required = true) @QueryParam("password") String password) {
    return Response.ok()
        .entity("logged in user session:" + System.currentTimeMillis())
        .build();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/logout")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Logs out current logged in user session",
    position = 7)
  public Response logoutUser() {
    return Response.ok().entity("").build();
  }
}
```

### Here is my jars

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywm1H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx753.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have to do with the `ApiAuthorizationFilterImpl` in `Jersey2Config` of `web.xml`.

The comment of this class states:

```
/**
 * The rules are maintained in simple map with key as path and a boolean value
 * indicating given path is secure or not. For method level security the key is
 * combination of http method and path.
 *
 * If the resource or method is secure then it can only be viewed using a
 * secured api key
 *
 * Note: Objective of this class is not to provide fully functional
 * implementation of authorization filter. This is only a sample demonstration
 * how API authorization filter works.
 *
 */
```

and the method `isOperationAllowed` states that all methods which are not get or if path starts with `'store` need to be checked whether key available. (quickly deducted so might be wrong).

So it might all work if you remove the filter.

Comment: @biswarupbannerjee please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: I am newbie in stack overflow. Please tell me how to do that